# typedef array with multiple arrays

Tags: c++, c, arrays, struct, typedef

I want to be able to do this:

```
typedef int a[2], b[2], c[2];
```

without having to type the `[2]`. One solution is to do:

```
typedef struct { int a[2] } a, b, c;
```

but then you have to always do stuff like `a.a[0]` and that's no good.

Comment: So you're asking for advanced solution? Or determined to be able to do this?

Comment: typedef  char[2] char_2; char_2 a,b,c;

Comment: a) I don't get why you are doing this. b) Chose C *or* C++, they have quite different type aliasing rules.

Comment: Is this different than a 2 dimensional array:  `int f[3][2]`? With indices matching the variables, such as `a==f[0][x]` and `b==f[1][x]` and `c==f[2][x]`?

Comment: Do you want the syntax for a `typedef` for an array of 2 integers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For C or C++98, a simple typedef will do:

```
typedef int int2[2];
int2 a, b, c;
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, the question is tagged with C++ and C, but there is a simple C++11 solution:

```
using int_arr = int[2];
int_arr a, b, c;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather define a more reusable type and SIMD friendly i.e.

```
template<typename T, int size>
struct type_t {
    // 32-byte AVX aligned ready for [gnu] auto-vectorization 
    typedef T array_t[size] __attribute__((aligned(32)));
};

typedef type_t<int, 2>::array_t int_array2;
typedef type_t<double, 2>::array_t double_array2;

// and then
int_array2 a, b, c;
double_array2 d, e, f;
```